Firebase App Check (RTDB) failure mode for unverified requests
I have an app deployed through Play that initially did not have Firebase App Check configured.  I now integrated App Check into the App without enabling "Enforce" and observed over time after publishing that verified requests increase, but not reaching 100%.
When "Enforce" is enabled and some installs have yet to upgrade, what then is the failure mode for various RTDB calls such as:

For unverified requests, does the following call succeed?  Or throw an exception?  Or return null?
// (1)
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


And if (1) succeeds, what of:
For unverified requests, does the following call succeed?  Or throw an exception?  Or return null?
// (2)
DatabaseReference rootDb = db.getReference();


Finally if (1) and (2) both succeed, what of:
For unverified requests, does the following call complete (and what of task.isSuccessful) ?  Or throw an exception ?  Or not return at all?
// (3)
rootDb.child("test").child("testRead").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
          Log.e(TAG,"Error reading from fb");
      } else {
          Log.d(TAG,"Good database read: "+task.getResult().getValue());
      }
  }
});



I'd rather not enable "Enforce" just to find out the results as that will potentially cause crashes in unverified installations/requests.

Calls 1 and 2 will definitely succeed, as they're pure client-side operation and App Check is only enforced on the server.
Call 3 will fail (for clients without a valid App Check token) with an permission denied error, same as when your security rules would reject the operation.
